# WebEssentials compiles from IDE, doesn't compile from CLI

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

I have several bundles of JavaScript files, which I want to minify and concatenate during the build. My project has several `*.js.bundle` files, which are somehow processed by WebEssentials when I issue the build command from GUI (pressing the button or hitting the hotkey).

However, when I'm trying to build the project, WebEssentials doesn't do a thing. I have added some logging into the project file to make sure the build runs and is up to date - it is all good, I can see my own messages being printed. But WebEssentials just doesn't appear anywhere in the build log :(

This is Visual Studio 2012 RC2.

One more, somewhat related thing is: I'd really like to have more control over how files are bundled. If at all possible, I'd like to use MSBuild (project) file to determine what is bundled, and where should it output the result.

If you happen to know where is the documentation, or... can I hope, for source code of WebEssentials? - that would help me understand what did they do there.

Answer (score 0):

The files are being compiled/updated when you save changes in source code files.
Take a look at the options withing visual studio (options > WebEssentials) and post feature requests to the developers.

http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general

Saving works for me, if it doesn't work on save, try checking the paths within .bundle file, sometimes they cannot be resolved correctly if you move the source and/or .bundle

You can reference () files from any place, so just create .bundle where you would like to have the output.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I don't even open Visual Studio / my goal is to avoid opening it. I needed to do this in order to automate the compilation process, but in the end I switched to use AjaxMin task - this is really a lot easier / less clutter.